# Freemarker request scoped variable for spring.binding

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker with Spring MVC.

In this code, when I try to bind the local variable "Price" for the nested object in the delete form, it fails with no object available for binding. In JSTL I've solved this nested object problem before by adding the nested price to the request scope with `<c:set />`.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Freemarker? or perhaps a recommended alternative approach?

```
<#list product.prices as price>                           
<tr>
    <td>${price.priceList.name}</td>
    <td>${price.priceList.currency}</td>
    <td>${DateUtils.formatTime(price.startTime!)}</td>
    <td>${DateUtils.formatTime(price.endTime!)}</td>
    <td>${price.price}</td>
    <td>${price.wasPrice}</td>
    <td class="center"><span class="green"><#if price.active><i class="fa fa-check"></i></#if></span></td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" href="/admin/products/new/${product.id}/prices/edit/${price.id}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <@spring.messageText "button.edit" "button.edit" /></a>

        <form class="inline" action="/admin/products/new/${product.id}/prices/delete/${price.id}" method="post">
            <@forms.csrf />
            <@forms.hiddenInput path="price.id" />

            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> <@spring.messageText "button.delete" "button.delete" />
            </button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</#list>
```

Comment: Hey, which part of the code fails? `<@forms.hiddenInput path="price.id" />` Also, what exactly are you trying to do? Just output the hidden input value? There is definitely a way to do what you want in FreeMarker...I just need to understand exactly what it is.

Comment: in the request I've got a product with a list of prices. I want to set up a form that targets the price directly, whether it's updating the price.id, or potentially another field. Check out the first line, where I'm looping the price list from the parent product, then setting up distinct forms for each...

Comment: It is the nested Price that fails saying there's no object "price" in the request. I can bind to product.price[price_index] - but then when it submits back it submits back a product, where I want it to submit back a price directly....